# Load module with parameter after bundle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, bundling-and-minification, jspm

I've got the following codeblock in the `layout.js`

```
import $ from "jquery";
import LayoutModel from 'js/models/LayoutModel';

let elements = {
    $window: $(window),
    $html: $('html'),
    $content: $('#content')
};

let viewmodel = null;

export function init(options) {
    viewmodel = new LayoutModel(options, elements);

    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, elements.$content[0]);
}
```

and I load it in the view with system.js and call the `init()` with options. The options contains values and it has to be in the view because some of it comes from the back-end model.

```
System.import('resources/javascript/layout').then(function(controller) {
    var options = {
        something: 'value'
    };
    controller.init(options);
});
```

This solution works while it's not bundled with jspm:

```
jspm bundle resources\javascript\layout resources\javascript\dist\layout.min.js --minify
```

In production I have to do it, but in this case I'm not able to use the `system.import()` and the `.then()`, because I have to load the bundled script with a normal `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="resources\javascript\dist\layout.min.js"></script>
```

**So the question**: How can I bundle and minify it and call the `init()` method with the options?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can make another script that will just import the `LayoutModel` and instantiate it with `viewmodel = new LayoutModel(options, elements);` and this script will be part of the bundle version.

Comment: @Martin: The example above was just a pure sample of my much more complex code. I have to use the options in the layout.js as well as in the LayoutModel.js and some other places too. So I should find solution for this logic.